# Force <div></div> to the bottom of the web page centered

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have a `<div>...</div>` section in my HTML that is basically like a toolbar.

Is there a way I could force that section to the bottom of the web page (the document, not the viewport) and center it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

It's an elegant, **CSS only** solution!

I use it and it works perfect with all kinds of layouts in all browsers! As far as I'm concerned it is the only elegant solution which works with all browsers and layouts.

@Josh: No it isn't and that's what Blankman wants, he wants a footer that sticks to the bottom of the document, not of the viewport (browser window). So if the content is shorter than the browser window, the footer sticks to the lower end of the window, if the content is longer, the footer goes down and is not visible until you scroll down.

#### Twitter Bootstrap implementation

I've seen a lot of people asking how this can be combined with Twitter Bootstrap. While it's easy to figure out, here are some snippets that should help.

```
// _sticky-footer.scss SASS partial for a Ryan Fait style sticky footer

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -1*($footerHeight + 2); /* + 2 for the two 1px borders */
}

.push {
  height: $footerHeight;
}

.wrapper > .container {
  padding-top: $navbarHeight + $gridGutterWidth;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .push {
    height: $topFooterHeight !important;
  }
  .wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto -1*($topFooterHeight + 2) !important;
  }
}
```

And the rough markup body:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        // navbar content
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            // main content with your grids, etc.
        </div>
        <div class="push"><!--//--></div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        // footer content
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Is the footer always visible?  Regardless of scroll position?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, you want the **toolbar** to *always* be visible, regardless of the vertical scroll position.  If that is correct, I would recommend the following CSS...

```
  body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:0;
  }

  #toolbar {
    background:#ddd;
    border-top:solid 1px #666;
    bottom:0;
    height:15px;
    padding:5px;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1000;
  }
```

Comment: Josh, any cross browser issues with this technique?

Comment: Well, I know that IE6 doesn't support fixed positioning.  But I tried it in IE7 and FF2 and it works.

Comment: @Hector I wonder if adding position:relative to the body fixes that

Comment: position:relative makes it so it doesn't stick to the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to be clear on what your saying here:

> bottom of the web page (the
>   **document**, not the *viewport*)

Naturally, a div will be at the bottom of the "document", depending on your layout.

If it's not going to the bottom of a document, or not paying attention to how tall your columns are, is it because your floating? Clear: both; would be in order to solve that.

The sticky footers are what I think your looking for, but when you say document, and not the viewport, I get a bit confused. Sticky footers typically do this: Watch for short pages, and if its shorter than the view port, the sticky footer tacks the footer div to the bottom.

Here's some sticky footers (there's gajillions of em, but this is in order of my favorites):

- http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/
- http://css-tricks.com/sticky-footer/
- http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ *(listed previously)*
- http://brassblogs.com/blog/sticky-footer
- [http://alistapart.com/](http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/spointfooter.htm) *(theres one there I just can't find it)*

Maybe if you gave a quick illustration or were a bit more specific on what you want? Hope this helps :D

-Ken

Comment: I think he just ment that if the document is longer than the viewport, the footer should not show until you scroll to the end. which is a sticky footer. with position absolute you would get a sticky viewport-footer which is in most cases ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Fixed footers without Javascript](http://boagworld.com/technology/fixed_footers_without_javascri/). I don't know if it will be a perfect fit, but I think it's close enough.

Comment: Doesn't work when resizing the browser for me.  Looks good otherwise -- snaps to the bottom of the document or, if the document doesn't scroll, to the bottom of the viewport (instead of just floating).

Answer (score 0):

You can just give the div a:

**clear:both; text-align:center;**

and put the div as the last element before the closing body statement. That would force it to be the last element without anything next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use javascript to determine the size of your page. You can get the height with window.innerHeight with non-IE browsers and document.documentElement.clientHeight with IE. With that value you should be able to absolutely position your element on the page setting top to that value minus the height of your div. If the height of your div is variable you will need to check the div's offsetHeight property to get the real height.

For centering use the following example:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style>
            .wrapper
            {
                width: 100%;
                padding-left: 50%;
            }
            .test
            {
                width: 400px;
                margin-left: -200px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding-left: -200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="test">This is a test</div>
    </div>
 </html>
```

You have a wrapper div around the div you want centered. The wrapper div has a width of 100% the inner div has a width set to whatever you want it to be. Give the wrapper div a left padding of 50% and the inner div a negative left margin equal to half of its width.

Comment: -1 because it talks about the viewport, that's not what he wants!